# Is there a way to get people's Facebook liked Pages?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm currently developing an app, and I was wandering if there is a way to get a user's Facebook liked pages. I looked intro the Facebook SDK but all I found was Facebook login, sharing, analytics and monetization.

Basically what I want is to access the user's liked Pages so I can make recommendations to the user based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible through the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

According to the official documentation, you should integrate the official [Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android) to your application. The following snippet might solve your needs. Take a look on the GraphResponse object results:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/likes",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Your app will need to be approved for `user_likes` permission, however, to be able to use this. You can still test with users who have a role in the app though.